# Systemd Journald accessing wrong location - fails to open /run/log/journal file

Tags: 20.04, systemd, systemd-journald

I was playing with BPF tools today (from Brendan Gregg's [BPF Book](http://www.brendangregg.com/bpf-performance-tools-book.html)) and ran the command `sudo opensnoop-bpfcc -x -U` and noticed many traces like this:

```
0     403    systemd-journal    -1   2 /run/log/journal/5c01742aed6d4d58bed5f1671e612657/system.journal
```

This is my main Lenovo p72 machine running Ubuntu 20.04 ...

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 10:28:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

While looking into this I found that there is nothing in `/run/log/journal`:

```
$ ls -al /run/log/journal/
total 0
drwxr-sr-x+ 2 root systemd-journal 40 Jun 28 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root            60 Jun 28 15:06 ..
```

... and `/run` is indeed a temp filesystem:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep run
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=6554292k,mode=755 0 0
```

Why would journald try to access a file in a location that just doesn't exist, on a temp filesystem mount? Is something configured wrong? Even when I edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and change the config to `Storage=parsistent`, journald still tries to access `/run/log`. The only correct location is `/var/log/journal/` where the path exists on my system, and it does write stuff to that location. This also happens to a second machine running the same OS listed below.

**update 2020-07-24 11:44:27**

```
> grep -v '#' /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf | sed '/^$/d'
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*
```

Comment: Post the output of the following command: `grep -v '#' /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf | sed '/^$/d'`

Comment: in systemd the default output is journal, (otherwise you have to set it with StandardOutput=  , more in systemd.exec(5)) , the output of the my previous comment was not necessary. BTW in the `/run/systemd/journal/streams` directory  you will find some configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is normal and ok.

- During the early boot phase the `/var` directory is not mounted and ready to write log files on the hard-disk. Therefore memory is used for storing and log-data is written to `/run/log/journal`. After it is mounted, all the data get's flushed into the disk (systemd-journactl-flush.service).
- Afterwards the systemd service manager invokes all service processes with standard output and standard error connected to the journal by default. Hence, the data streams are piped through from the unit to the run directory, and further to `/var/log`.